# Why does this code produce strange, unexpected output?

Tags: c++, pointers, double, cout

Why am I not getting a proper result?

I don't get a proper output of px although I have it named as a double I am getting some freaking number-text mashup as a result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
double a = 0; double b = 0; double c = 0; double x = 0;
cout << "Welcome to Lytis! \nPlease enter a:";
cin >> a;
cout << "Please enter b:";
cin >> b;
cout << "Please enter c:";
cin >> c;
if (a != 0){
    double d = (b*b) - (4 * a * c);
}
f (d == 0){
        double x =  -(b) / (2 * a);
        double *px = &x;
        cout << "The only solution is x=" << px;
        cin.get();
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: #Why #are #you #using #hashtags?

Comment: I think you get a hex number out, your printing the address of the pointer. Read up on pointers and you shall find your solution.

Comment: You're missing parts of your actual code. This code does not compile, so it *has no behavior*. We can't tell you what's wrong with your program if you don't show us your actual code. Copy-and-paste your actual code into the question.

Comment: You didn't bother to explain what results you think you should get. You expect us to guess from your code but, as you point out yourself, your code _doesn't produce that output_. So your code is broken. How are we to know, then, what it is supposed to do?

Comment: ITT hex is "a freaking number-text mashup"

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Your code does not compile (e.g. `d` is not declared)

**2)** The "number-text meshup" is the **address of x** (the pointer) that you are printing out.

Use the dereference operator `*` to get the value pointed to :

```
cout << "The only solution is x=" << *px;
                                    ^^^
                                    Here
```

**3)** You should check the return value of `cin` to be safe against wrong inputs.

**4)** ["Lytis" means "Sex" in Lithuanian.](https://translate.google.com/#lt/en/Lytis)

Comment: *Your code does not compile (e.g. `d` is not declared)* -- I would have stopped right there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears px is of type `double *`, so outputting it as such is printing out a memory location (usually expressed in hexadecimal, i.e. 0-9 A-F ).

The assignment `double *px = &x` is legit, as it is assigning a reference (memory location) to a pointer, but when you output a pointer with `cout` it will display its location.

Maybe try:

```
cout << "The only so....." << *px;
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution!